# How to convert integer value from python to smallint postgresql?

Tags: python, django

I have a function written in the Postgresql database and have to call it from the Django view in Python. The function has parameters of smallint type.
In Python, it looks like

```
   str = "02"
    plist = [int(str)]
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from some_func(%s);", plist)
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        ...
```

Calling this code in my HTML template I see the following message:
function some_function(integer) does not exist
That's because the type of parameter is smallint
How should I convert my string in order to deliver it as smallint to the Postgresql database?

Comment: `(int)str` is invalid, it should be `int(str)`, (and you better do *not* name a variable `str` in the first place).

Comment: I see. In fact I have int(str). That's not exactly the code. The code is more complicated.

Comment: "function some_function(integer) does not exist That's because the type of parameter is smallint"; afaic that's a wrong conclusion.

Comment: I think you need to do `plist[0]`, so as to pass int to `some_func()`.

Comment: I made an experiment. Wrote a function in Postgresql that converts the input parameter from integer to smallint and calls the original one. And this works.